# Low Level keyboard hook c++

Tags: c++, winapi, keyboard-hook

I tried to create an application in c++ that sets a low level keyboard hook 
and each time the user presses a key it will write a char of a string I made.

Can someone explain how can I change the user input without using the 
keybd_event function but changing the key itself before the OS interprets it.

I tried something with ths MSG and changing the wparam but it didn't work.
If someone can show me a code example it will 
be better

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#WH_KEYBOARD_LL) already ?

Comment: yes I leared how to install the hook with that and I read everything in MSDN about setwindowshookex, wh_keybored_LL, keybd_event and MSG but didnt get my answer anywhere

Answer (score 2):

> Can someone explain how can I change the user input without using the keybd_event function but changing the key itself before the OS interprets it.

You cannot.  You have to reject the key inyour hook and then post your own key using `keybd_event()` or `SendInput()`.  And be sure to check if the `KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT::flags` field has the `LLKHF_INJECTED` or `LLKHF_LOWER_IL_INJECTED` flag enabled so you don't reject your own simulated keys.

> I tried something with ths MSG and changing the wparam but it didn't work

The `MSG` structure is not used with a `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` hook.